# Are Drupal theme settings cached?

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes, drupal-theming, drupal-cache

i want to change theme_username, a core theme function that outputs that dreadful "not verified" string on users who are not logged in (when they comment, for example). i want a checkbox in admin/build/themes/settings/MYTHEME to change that. but since that theme function gets called a lot, will it hurt the performance of any site using my theme or *are theme settings cached*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theme settings are cached as specified in the Drupal API page for [`theme_get_setting($setting_name, $refresh = FALSE)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_get_setting/6).

Answer (score 0):

Theme settings is usually stored with variable_set. So you need a query to check it. But you can cache the result yourself, with a static variable.